# Issues adding github account to visual studio 2022

Tags: github, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to create a Git repository in Visual Studio 2022, when i signed in,it directed me to a browser where everything was successful and on returning to my Visual Studio project i got an error: aka.ms.githubonvs, I have been on this issue for weeks now. Please someone should guide me through.

I have tried going to tool and account to change from embedded browser to system web browser all to no avail.

I'm having the below error when i tried add git account in visual studio 2022 create repository: **there was a problem adding your github account. for help signing in go to aka.ms/githubonvs**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.